# Syntax of echo incorrect in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

No idea whats going on here, so I hope someone can help.

I have a batch file that echos this:

```
echo +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
echo | Booking System                                                           |
echo | By IT Department                                                         |
echo +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
echo | IF YOU CAN SEE THIS, SOMETHING BROKE!                                    |
echo +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
echo | IF YOU CAN NOT SEE THE BOOKING INTERFACE,PLEASE USE THE PHONE AND DIAL 0 |
echo +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
echo |                                                                          |
echo +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I run the script, is gives me a Syntax error:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies with:

```
echo | Booking System |
```

The `|` is the pipe character which takes the output of the `echo` and tries to connect it to the standard input of a program called `Booking` (which probably doesn't exist) using the argument `System`, and then taking the output of *that* program and piping through to, well, nothing.

Hence the error, a syntax error caused by the final pipe with no program to run.

You should escape the pipe characters thusly:

```
echo ^| these will be treated as literal bar characters ^|
```

See the following transcript which shows a coup[le of errors caused by unescaped pipes (including the second one which matches your case) and the fix:

```
C:\users\Pax\Documents> echo | hello there
'hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\users\Pax\Documents> echo | hello there |
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\users\Pax\Documents> echo ^| hello there ^|
| hello there |
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for explaining it. :D